# Exclude usernames from tweets, using regular expressions, in RapidMiner

Tags: regex, twitter, regex-negation, rapidminer

Working on a sentiment analysis problem, I am trying to exclude the usernames from the text of tweets. For example, having the following tweet.

```
`Hey @SOCommunity check this out!`
```

I'm trying to keep just this

```
`Hey check this out!`
```

So far I've seen how to select the username `@\S+\s+` and I've tried to negate it using this expression `^(?!@\S+\s+)\w+` which only captures the `Hey` leaving out the rest of it.

How should I edit the expression to also catch the rest of the tweet?

Comment: First of all, don't use `@\S+\s+` to match a username because you'll match false-positives. For a Twitter username, you may use something like `@\w{1,15}\b`. Second, why can't you just match the username and then remove it from the string (replace it with an empty string)? What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rapid Miner which I still don't know what capabilities does it have that is why I'm trying to do both operations with regEx. Nice idea about the pattern I didn't know that a twitter username can be up to 15 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to replace the user name from the text. Sed command `sed 's/@[a-zA-Z0-9]* //'`

Ex:

```
 echo 'Hey @SOCommunity1 check this out!' | sed 's/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]\{1,15\} //'
```

Output:

```
Hey check this out!
```

To apply `sed` command against a file named `tweets.tx`

```
sed 's/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]\{1,15\} //' tweets.txt
```

Comment: I'm using RapidMiner, I'm not sure if I can make use of sed. This was my fault not to mention it.

Comment: A Twitter handle might contain an underscore, so you should include that in your character class. Also, this pattern will match `@` not followed by a username. It's better to replace `*` with `+` (or `{1,15}` to be more accurate).

Comment: If you have all the text in a file, you can apply the sed command to replace all the username then use that file in rapidminer.

Comment: I agree with both of you, I will change my pattern and I will do some ETL manually using also `sed` for this replacement, since I'm still not very familiar with RapidMiner.

Comment: Thanks, @AhmedAbdelhameed for pointing that out. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you want is separate in groups like that:

```
@villos hey dude
(user)  (twett)
```

you can do this with it regex...

```
^(@.+?)\s+?(.*)$
```

here is full example:
https://regex101.com/r/tG2vR4/1

Comment: Thank you for the example but I think that this would only work if a twitter username was explicitly in the beginning of a tweet, but in reality could be anywhere in the text of a tweet. Could you confirm that please?

Comment: This pattern a) allows false-positives. b) will only work if the username is at the beginning of the string. c) doesn't take into account that a tweet might contain multiple usernames.